how to capture a partial consumer group failure in Prometheus using PromQL?
I want to explore the possibilities of capturing any sort of partial consumer group failures due to any reason using PromQL in Prometheus. So that I can use that metrics to monitor and later can add a Grafana alert to get notified.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Prometheus isn't used for such error log capturing. Did you look at JMX at all?
